# How to solve a competitve programming task with dynamic programming? (CodeForces)

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

The condition is:

> Ayoub and Kilani felt board while they are going to ArabellaCPC in
>   (Amman-Irbid) road, so Kilani invented a new game to play with Ayoub.
>
> The game is described by the following rules :
>
> Ayoub picks a random integer `n (1≤n≤109)` , and Kilani picks a random
>   integer `k (1≤k≤n)`, then they will start playing. In each turn a player
>   can choose any number `x (1≤x≤max(1,m−k))` (which m is the current value
>   of `n`) and subtract it from `n`. if `n` equals `zero` then the player can't
>   make a move. The player who can't make a move is considered to lose
>   the game.
>
> If Kilani starts, and each player played optimally, who would be the
>   winner?

Actually, I am a fresh-water in competivie programming and totally cannot come up with right idea. I have written something, but I cannot get is this right way, because it gives me wrong results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>
#include <deque>
#include <cmath>

int bestWin(int m, int k)
{
    if (m - k <= 0)
        return 0;

    std::vector<int> availableNumbers(m - k);
    std::iota(availableNumbers.begin(), availableNumbers.end(), 1);

    std::vector<int> possibleWins;

    for (auto i = 0; i < availableNumbers.size(); i++)
    {
        possibleWins.push_back(bestWin(m - availableNumbers[i], k));
    }

    return *std::max_element(possibleWins.begin(), possibleWins.end()) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int testCases;
    std::cin >> testCases;

    while (testCases--)
    {
        int n, k;

        std::string numbers;
        std::cin.get();
        std::getline(std::cin, numbers);
        std::istringstream iNumbers(numbers);
        iNumbers >> n; iNumbers >> k;

        std::cout << bestWin(n, k);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could you explain me please what an approach should I use? I guess it is dynamic programming... I do not know where can I ask a help anywhere else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dynamic programming to solve this problem. Consider the following:

- When `n <= k+1` then the only value that can be chosen for `x` is `1` (x<=max(1, n-k)
- When `n > k+1` you can choose any value for `x` so Kilani will always win by choosing `n-k` or `n-k-1` and reaching `k` or `k+1` (explained below)

For the first point you just need to check wether `k` is odd or even, because Kilani can reach `k` in one move and after that players will alternate removing `1` each round. In that case, if `k` is odd Ayoub wins and Kilani wins otherwise.

For the second point, depending on the parity of `k` Kilani can pick `n-k` or `n-k-1`, For example:

```
n = 10, k = 3
Kilani chooses max(1, m-k) = max(1, 10-3-1) = 6
n = 4
Ayoub chooses max(1, m-k) = max(1, (any number)-3) = 1
n = 3
then they keep alternating picking ones and Kilani will win
```

So you could modify your code to do:

```
while (testCases--)
{
    int n, k;

    std::string numbers;
    std::cin.get();
    std::getline(std::cin, numbers);
    std::istringstream iNumbers(numbers);
    iNumbers >> n; iNumbers >> k;

    if (n-k == 1 && (k&1)) {
        std::cout << "Ayoub";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Kilani";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have been looking for an explanation for this solution (I've found a same one in github)! I hope someone else will be intrested in the explanation!